# DidReceivedLocalNotificaiton not called when localNotification.alertBody is commented

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uilocalnotification

I have following line of code to generate local notification after every 1 minute (For Testing), It works perfectly in following condition.

1. When application is in running state.
2. When application is in background state and and localNotification.alertBody = @"Local Notification Received" is not commented.

Now when i comment the "localNotification.alertBody" it works fine when application is in running state but didn't work when application is in background state.

Following is the line of code to create local notification.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[localNotification setRepeatInterval:NSMinuteCalendarUnit];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
localNotification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
//localNotification.alertBody = @"Local Notification Received";
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[localNotification release];
```

in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

```
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
        self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to execute code in the background, without showing a notification to the user.

By definition, UILocalNotification will not display a popup if alertBody is nil, even though didReceiveLocalNotification will be called PROVIDED THAT THE APPLICATION IS RUNNING.

If the application is in the background and alertBody is empty, then no popup alert and no execution of any code.

Answer (score 2):

From the [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **alertBody**
>
> ...
>
> Assign a string or, preferably, a localized-string key (using NSLocalizedString) as the value of the message. If the value of this property **is non-nil, an alert is displayed**. The default value is nil (**no alert**).

Are you sure that `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` has not been called at all? Or is it just the alert you are missing?

Comment: Well what i want to do is that if application is in background state then i don't want to show any message and let the didReceiveLocalNotification called... in fact at no time i want to show any alret message and call didReceiveLocalNotification after interval.

Comment: That should be achieved by your code. Are you sure, `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` is not called? Have you put some logging into that method?

Comment: Please update your question with the code instead of putting it into a comment for better readability.